# Run python from laravel

Tags: python, php, laravel, symfony-process

I'm trying to run a python script from Laravel, with Symfony `Process` component like this :

My controller :

```php
public function access(Request $request)
{
    $process = new Process(['test.py', 'helloworld']);
    $process->run();
    dd($process->getOutput());
}
```

Python script :

```python
import sys
x = sys.argv[1]
print(x)
```

But all i get in dd is `""`

What do you think is the problem ?

Comment: Python files are not executable files, unless they have a shebang + execution permission and you run it from a shell. Instead of this, you should add the python interpreter as the 1st array argument, something like this (not tested at all): `new Process(['/usr/bin/python', 'test.py', 'helloworld'])`

Comment: Same result.. I don't know how i can execute a py script from laravel

Comment: Can you try by replacing your python filename with a full path? Something like `new Process(['/usr/bin/python', '/my/full/path/test.py', 'helloworld'])`

Comment: Still nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a tip but too long to fit as a comment:

Instead of dumping only the standard output, you can dump as well other useful information:

```
$process = new Process(['/usr/bin/python', '/my/full/path/test.py', 'helloworld']);
$process->run();

echo "Output:\n";
dump($process->getOutput());
echo "Error:\n";
dump($process->getErrorOutput());
echo "Exit code: " . $process->getExitCode() . "\n";
die;
```

Comment: Thank you i got this as the ErrorOutPut : """
Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
Python runtime state: preinitialized
"""

Comment: Hitting the same issue.  Might be because my build environment is Windows. I also read this: https://www.scivision.dev/python-calling-python-subprocess/  but I've not figured out a solution.  Did you ever resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony process keeps throwing **Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init** error, used **shell_exec()** instead.

```
 <?php
    $var = "Hello World";
    $command = escapeshellcmd('path_to_python_script.py '.$var);
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
 ?>
```

you can also send file instead of variable and have it handled from python. if you want to get runtime inputs checkout [**Brython**](https://brython.info/) or [**Skulpt**](https://skulpt.org/).